# Contact form for magento

Tags: php, html, magento

How can open my contact us form from the top i.e., title.
I am facing a problem that the contact page opens from the form by skipping the content before the form ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope, you will find solution here.

http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-edit-contact-us-page.html

Or

http://www.atwix.com/magento/customizing-contact-us/

Cheers...

Comment: Can i use any special symbols for representing url in magento ?

Comment: I tried using the symbol '#' for changing the url of my contact page . I couldnot open it from the start upon opening the site . Can you suggest me how it can be done ?